# Sending Notification Messages in C#

Tags: c#

I have to make a development in an already built up Windows form application in C# as a part of my studies. 
This application should work as follows. This application will be used in a work place department consists of Executives and their Manager. Executives will work on certain findings with regard to various issues and once they investigate a finding, this application has the facility to upload that finding.However, to publish the finding it should have the approval of the manager of the department. My task is to set a button which should work as once it is pressed the manager should receive a notification message such as "You have a finding for your approval from "Executive Name". Executives will log into the system using their username and password and manager also has a separate username and password. Executives and the managers will be in the same server and if the manager was not logged in to the application on the time of sending the notification, it should be appeared when the time he logged into the application.
Does anyone have the details of sending these sort of notification messages in C#. I have tried a lot in Google, but was not successful. If anyone can help me on this appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Is an email not sufficient?

Comment: It will also serve the necessity.A notification message which will appear in the task bar of the manager will be the optimum solution. However, if you can guide me to an auto generated email it will also helpful since i don't have any solution in my hand on this time.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you would need to create a database abstraction for "messages" or "notifications."  The schema may look like this:

```
Messages
--------
Id  uniqueidentifier not null primary key
UserId  uniqueidentifier not null
IsRead  bit null
Text  varchar(MAX) null
```

So, when a message is read, you would send (probably) an AJAX request to update the `IsRead` field to show that the message was read.  You could also use AJAX to check to see if the user has any messages that are not yet read, and show them on the UI.

If you have any other questions, let us know.

**Edit:**  How to use AJAX with MVC and jQuery.

Create an action like this in your controller:

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult GetMessagesForUser()
{
    // get user ID
    Guid userId = YourIdentityProvider.User.Id;

    // check messages like this:
    var messages = from m in ctx.Messages
                    where m.UserId == userId
                    && m.IsRead == false
                    select m;

    return Json(messages.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, in your view, check for a new message every few seconds like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMessagesForUser")',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // new messages
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Tks & I will try on these and let you know. Appreciate if you can provide me a link(if you have) to read about this more. Any other ways are also welcome.

Comment: Sorry. I need a clarification. I'm in need of a method of sending messages. Not to check whether the message is read or not.

Comment: You send the message by saving it to the database.  Then, on the client side, you use AJAX to check to see if the user has any unread messages.  Are you using MVC or webforms?

Comment: @ user1477388 It's MVC

Answer (score 0):

Seems that using event is good in the case. when the button is pressed the event of button pressed is raised and since manager and executives were subscribed to the event, they'll be notified

Comment: Could you please clarify on this more.

Comment: @Udith Posted a new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.yourButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(ManagerEventHandler);
 this.yourButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(ExecutiveEventHandler);
private void ManagerEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//TODO
}

private void ExecutiveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//TODO
}
```